# Get Powershell object from out of process runspace

Tags: c#

I am running powershell scripts in C# in an out of process runspace for isolation. I have some complex types that are returned from the scripts, but they are not fully returned- I only get the name of the type as a string. If i run n the same runspace as C#, i have full access to the object innards. How can I get the full object when running in a separate runspace?

ex:

```
using ( var run = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null) )
{
    run.Open();
    using ( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
    {
        ps.Runspace = run; //commenting this out gives me the full object in data
        ps.AddScript("Get-Process");
        var data = ps.Invoke(); //has array, but each baseobject is empty
    }
}
```